# Is Stack Overflow search broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm not getting any results when I search SO or Meta SO.

For example, [here's an SO post containing the words 'remove' and 'javascript'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156723/java-best-way-to-remove-javascript-from-html) in the title.

However, here's what I get when I search for *remove javascript* on SO:

[image]

Ordinarily, I would search Meta SO for posts about this, but the Meta SO search seems to be wonky too.

Comment: It's working again now. Probably a hiccup.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162013/non-tag-search-is-not-working-on-mso

Comment: I kinda sorta crashed the master search node earlier, we got it back up fairly quickly though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks OK to me:

[image: remove js 26k results]

Comment: nice--looks like we're back in business. :)